# how can I get the general expression of the outer product of n sublists?

Tags: list-manipulation

There is a large list, with $n$ sublists of the same length (e.g. length is 3).

```
list1 = {{a_1, b_1, c_1}, {a_2, b_2, c_2},..., {a_n, b_n, c_n}}
```

If I need to regard $n$ as a parameter, how can I get the general expression of the outer product of the sublists?

Maybe we need to make some change to the code like this?

```
Outer[List, list1[[1]], list1[[2]], ...., list1[[n]], 1]
```

Should we use loop? or there will be better method?

Comment: try `Outer[List, Sequence @@ list1]`?

Comment: Also, I notice you're using `Outer[List, ...]`; just in case you plan to flatten this outer product, note the existence of `Tuples[list1]`

Answer (score 1):

Define a function that generates a suitable list of triplets:

```
lists[n_] := Array[a[#1][#2] &, {n, 3}]

lists[2]
(* {{a[1][1], a[1][2], a[1][3]}, {a[2][1], a[2][2], a[2][3]}} *)
```

We can apply `Outer` to such a list e.g.

```
Outer[Times, ##] & @@ lists[2]
(* {{a[1][1] a[2][1], a[1][1] a[2][2], 
  a[1][1] a[2][3]}, {a[1][2] a[2][1], a[1][2] a[2][2], 
  a[1][2] a[2][3]}, {a[1][3] a[2][1], a[1][3] a[2][2], 
  a[1][3] a[2][3]}} *)
```